# List all unique values based on criterias

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to list all values that have a specific criteria in other columns as shown [image: here]

I have the following:

```
Sub arytest()

Dim ary()
Dim note2()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim eleAry, x

'Number of rows in my data file
lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'The maximum length of my array
ReDim ary(1 To lastrow)

k = 1
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 2) Like "*Note 2*" _   ' Criterias that needs to be fullfilled
    And Cells(i, 1) Like "Actuals" _
    And Cells(i, 4) Like "Digitale Brugere" Then
        ary(k) = Cells(i, 3)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This code lists all values I need. However some of them are present multiple times. How can I remove duplicates?

Comment: Have you tried removing duplicates based on 1 column (the one with duplicate values) if there are more columns with different data, remove duplicates don't work, but if you mark the column you want to check works just fine.

Comment: Hi @Damian. Thank you a lot for your input!
So this makro is something that i need to do 30 times. One for each area. This problem here is that i need to restore the original data. So i need it to be done in an array.

Comment: Does that work? I was giving you another approach with dictionaries.

Comment: s per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, so you won't need to remove duplicates later, using `Scripting Dictionary` (you need to check the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` on the libraries for this to work)

```
Sub arytest()

    Dim ary()
    Dim note2() 'unsued
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim eleAry, x 'unused
    Dim DictDuplicates As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set DictDuplicates = New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Number of rows in my data file
    lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'The maximum length of my array
    ReDim ary(1 To lastrow)

    k = 1
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        ' Criterias that needs to be fullfilled
        If Cells(i, 2) Like "*Note 2*" _
        And Cells(i, 1) Like "Actuals" _
        And Cells(i, 4) Like "Digitale Brugere" Then
            If Not DictDuplicates.Exists(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then 'check if the value is already on the array
                ary(k) = Cells(i, 3)
                DictDuplicates.Add Cells(i, 3).Value, i 'if it does not exists, add it to the dictionary
            End If
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I've also seen some variables unused on your code, or at least what you posted.

PS: when using the `Like`operator you should use the wildcards`*` or `?`, without them is the same as if you were using the `=` operator.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to mark it as an answer so others can find it.